obs-studio still being listed after 'sudo apt-get autoremove obs-studio'
I've been trying to set up obs-studio on my system, however, I kept running into the (known) issue of screen capture only displaying a blank screen with the cursor the only thing being captured.
I went through a couple troubleshooting steps, one of which involved removing the program and re-installing it, however, after running the following:
sudo apt-get autoremove obs-studio 

Then confirming that I removed the program
sudo obs
sudo: obs: command not found

And because I'm paranoid that I never do things correctly, I followed up with:
apt list --all-versions obs-studio
Listing... Done
obs-studio/jammy 30.1.2-0obsproject1~jammy amd64
obs-studio/jammy 27.2.3+dfsg1-1 amd64


and yet, it is still being listed as being on my computer. I tried to go through and find the program manually by sudo apt-get remove and hitting the TAB key twice and went through each removable install, but I couldn't find it.
If I try to run a remove command, I get the following
sudo apt-get remove obs-studio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'obs-studio' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.


Not sure why there are still listings?
I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

@steeldriver Please write it as an answer.

@ArchismanPanigrahi done ;)

The command apt list --all-versions obs-studio lists available versions of the software (by searching the package catalogue).
To list only installed software, you'd need
apt list --installed obs-studio

or (with the lower-level dpkg command)
dpkg -l obs-studio

